# Persisting domain model w/ list of enums not working in GORM/Grails

Tags: list, grails, groovy, enums, grails-orm

My model needs to have multiple enums of the same type:

```
class Broker {

    static constraints = {
        brokerTypes(nullable:false)
    }

    List<BrokerType> brokerTypes
}
```

The model is being instantiated with the params from the request, which has in it a list of BrokerTypes:

```
def save(){
        def brokerInstance = new Broker(newParams)
        System.out.println(brokerInstance.getBrokerTypes().toString());
        if (!brokerInstance.save(flush: true)) {
            render(view: "create", model: [brokerInstance: brokerInstance])
            return
        }
        redirect(action: "show", id: brokerInstance.id)
}
```

The println prints out the list of BrokerTypes as expected, so i know that it exists in the instance. Later, the model is retrieved as follows:

```
def brokerInstance = Broker.findByLatAndLon(lat,lon)
System.out.println(brokerInstance.getBrokerTypes().toString());
```

This time the println prints out 'null'

So i imagine the problem is that GORM doesn't know how to store this list of enums, and instead when the brokerInstance.save() is called, its saving the brokerTypes field as null.

Do i need to create a mapping somehow to get GORM to recognize the list? A hack alternative would be to instead of storing the list of enums, to store a list of strings or something and then map back to the enum when needed, but this doesnt seem clean

Comment: Everything seems correct, must be working. I have similar domain - everything is fine. PS Also, you can write it as `println brokerInstance.brokerTypes`

Answer (score 3):

You will have to use a `hasMany` clause so that grails/gorm initializes a one to many relationship

You should add the following snippet to your domain class.

```
   static hasMany = [brokerTypes : BrokerType]
```